# useSelector, and properly switching slices of data to avoid excessive slow downs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux

I have a list of objects - each with various properties... the list is about 4000 long.

there is a reason to filter and show a subsection of the slice based on a property of these objects... for example... selecting all of them that have the 'paid' bool set to true, or 'rush' bool.

this is my current code.

```
import {selectJobs,
    selectCompleteJobs,
    selectUncompleteJobs, 
    selectUnpaidJobs} from "../../slices/jobCardSlice";


// inside the component
const [selectors, setSelectors] = useState([selectUncompleteJobs,selectJobs,selectCompleteJobs,selectUnpaidJobs]); // an array of selectors
const found = selectors.find(x=>x===props.selector); //initial selector choosed
const [chosenSelector, setChosenSelector] = useState(selectors.indexOf(found)||0); //a number 
const jobs = useSelector(selectors[chosenSelector]); // the slice
const selectControls = (
    <select className="selectControls"  onChange={(e)=>{
    setChosenSelector(e.target.value);
}}>{selectors.map((x,i)=><option value = {i}>{x.name}</option>)}
    </select>
); // the thing that changes the slice a select element that selects a selector


var jobscards = jobs.map(jobDatat=>(<JobCard key={jobDatat.id} props={jobDatat} />));

// then it renders a box with the selector in the head - and a list of jobcards in the body (boxes have a head/title area, and a body/list area);
```

and here are the selectors, they are pretty basic.

```
export const selectJobs = (state) =>{
     return state.jobs;
}
export const selectNoData = (state)=>{
    return state.jobs.filter(x=>x.data===1);
}
export const selectCompleteJobs = (state) =>{
    return state.jobs.filter(x=>x.JobStatus === "COMPLETE");
}
export const selectUncompleteJobs = (state) =>{
    return state.jobs.filter(x=>x.JobStatus !== "COMPLETE");
}
export const selectUnpaidJobs = (state) =>{
    return state.jobs.filter(x=>x.paidStatus!== "PAID");
}
```

switching between small slices is just barely fast enough... however, if I change to a large slice - it takes more than 15 seconds to load in.

is there a better way to handle filtering of a selector? this is literally just the first thing that came to mind - it technically works but is no where close to production ready due to speed.

how do you handle filtering long lists? (also - the initial load in with all fresh data from the server: that first render is maybe one second - so I think there is a pattern that can be that fast...)

I'm new to react - and I haven't found anything about a good way of handling this yet.

EDIT: i have made the following changes to the slice.

```
//instead of the old selectors - they are now:


export const selectNoData = createSelector(
    //input selector all jobs
    selectJobs,
    jobs=>jobs.filter(x=>x.dataRecieved==1)

)

export const selectUnpaidJobs = createSelector(
    //input selector all jobs
    selectJobs,
    jobs=>jobs.filter(x=>x.hasBeenPaid !== "PAID")

)
export const selectUncompleteJobs = createSelector(
    //input selector all jobs
    selectJobs,
    jobs=>jobs.filter(j=>j.JobCompleted  !==  "COMPLETE")

)

export const selectCompleteJobs = createSelector(
    //input selector all jobs
    selectJobs,
    jobs=>jobs.filter(j=>j.JobCompleted === "COMPLETE")

)
```

this does improve performance down to 7 seconds instead of 15.

I'm still looking for further optimization - but that was a big step!

Answer (score 1):

The first issue here is that all of your selectors are always returning a new reference, by calling `state.jobs.filter()`.  That means that these components will be forced to re-render if other actions are dispatched, even if this data didn't actually change.

So, a key first step here is to update these selectors to be "memoized" so that they only recalculate the filtered lists if the input status changes.

See these posts for details:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#memoizing-selectors-with-createselector
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization#improving-render-performance
- https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/

That doesn't help the list itself render faster, but it will help avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Also, be sure that [you're applying appropriate `key` values to each list item, so that React can keep the list item components alive and reuse the contents](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#component-types-and-reconciliation).  It does look like you're doing that atm, but never hurts to double-check.

Comment: That's a fantastic resource... reading though it now... is there any conflict with redux toolkit's createSlice?

Comment: RTK actually comes with Reselect's `createSelector` built-in already - just import it.

Comment: I'm confused a bit still, should I take all the selectors I currently have as the inputs to a single createSelector function? or do I need to make multiple createSelectors for each selector currently? can you give an example of what the better/correct pattern is?

Comment: No, each of those selectors needs to be a separate call to `createSelector`.  See the examples in those links.

Comment: cool beans, and last question: is there access to the 'name' property of the function in createSelector anywhere - the option mapping with x.name is a null property once I put those in. I can hard code around it...

Comment: If you need to show a display value, I would create an explicit object mapping string keys to these selector functions, rather than relying on an implicit `function.name` field.